# HTML formatted report – email via PowerShell

Tags: arrays, windows, azure, powershell, powershell-3.0

**Use case**:

1. Generate AD Account created in the last 30 days
2. Export to as Csv or txt
3. Import data into html formatted report email to sysAdmin

Issue: Received email with all row data showing as: **System.Object[]**
**Step to repo:** 
Export data:

```html
$When = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-30)).Date
Get-ADUser -Filter {whenCreated -ge $When} -Properties Name, EmailAddress,SamAccountName, LastLogonDate,whenCreated, passwordlastset, Enabled, lockedout |
Select SamAccountName,Name,EmailAddress,LastLogonDate,whenCreated,passwordlastset,Enabled,lockedout | 
Export-Csv -Path "\iteminfo.txt" –NoTypeInformation
```

**Import to create report** as explained in this [post](https://www.powershellbros.com/create-your-own-html-report-email/)

```html
$users = Get-Content "\iteminfo.txt" 

# Table name
$tabName = "Report"

#Create Table object
$table = New-Object system.Data.DataTable "$tabName"

#Define Columns
$col1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "User Name",([string])
$col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Email Adderss",([string])
$col3 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Login ID",([string])
$col4 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Creation date",([string])
$col5 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Last logon date",([string])
$col6 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Last password reset",([string])
$col7 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Enabled",([string])
$col8 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Locked",([string])

#Add the Columns
$table.columns.add($col1)
$table.columns.add($col2)
$table.columns.add($col3)
$table.columns.add($col4)
$table.columns.add($col5)
$table.columns.add($col6)
$table.columns.add($col7)
$table.columns.add($col8)

ForEach ($item in $users)
{
        $userdata = (Get-ADUser -identity $item -properties Name,EmailAddress,SamAccountName,LastLogonDate,whenCreated,passwordlastset,Enabled,lockedout )
        
        #Create a row
        $row = $table.NewRow()

        #Enter data in the row
        $row."User name" = ($userdata."Name")
        $row."Email Address" = ($userdata."EmailAddress")
        $row."User ID" = ($userdata."SamAccountName")
        $row."Creation date" = ($userdata."created")
        $row."Last logon date" = ($userdata."LastLogonDate")
        $row."Last password reset" = ($userdata."PasswordLastSet")
        $row."Enabled" = ($userdata."Enabled")
        $row."Locked" = ($userdata."Lockedout")

        #Add the row to the table
        $table.Rows.Add($row)

}
#Communication template
#Creating head style
$Head = @"
 
<style>
  body {
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 8pt;
    color: #4C607B;
    }
  th, td { 
    border: 1px solid #e57300;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 5px;
    }
  th {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #003366;
    color: #ffffff;
    }
  td {
    color: #000000;
    }
  .even { background-color: #ffffff; }
  .odd { background-color: #bfbfbf; }
</style>
 
"@

# Creating body
[string]$body = [PSCustomObject]$table | select -Property "User name","Email Address","User ID","Creation date","Last logon date","Last password reset","Enabled","Locked" | sort -Property "User name"  | ConvertTo-HTML -head $head -Body "<font color=`"Red`"><h4> Account(s) Created In The Last 30 Days and Status </h4></font>
```

and i kept getting the system.object[] error, which i believe is likely due to how i import the data. Does anyone know how this can be fixed? 
[image: Received email]

Comment: `Get-Content` is used without `ConvertFrom-Csv` to get a psobject...That for sure alone will create problems since you deals which each csv line as string rather as objects. Not sure how you got the System.Object[] as I was unable to reproduce your result as is with your example. That being said, see my answer. The 2 examples within it work perfectly fine and do render properly.

Comment: Didn't know about the 'ConvertFrom-Csv', this is really an eye opener for me. Thanks a lot Sage, I'm checking the examples now and will revert back shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You example have some problems.

1. You need to convert the content to a PSObject using

`ConvertFrom-Csv` 
`$users = Get-Content "\iteminfo.txt" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Csv`

2. Some other errors found between the column definitions / assignments (Email Adderss / Email Address & Login ID / User ID
3. When doing your `ForEach ($item...)`, you will need to use `$item.SamAccountName` which will work since `ConvertFrom-csv` was implemented in the first step.
4. You actually do not need at all to use datatable / datarow object for that. You will usually have to deal with that if you query a SQL database. In your case, that's a layer of complexity that bring nothing to the table.

Here's the modified script

```
$When = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-30)).Date
Get-ADUser -Filter {whenCreated -ge $When} -Properties Name, EmailAddress,SamAccountName, LastLogonDate,whenCreated, passwordlastset, Enabled, lockedout |
Select SamAccountName,Name,EmailAddress,LastLogonDate,whenCreated,passwordlastset,Enabled,lockedout | 
Export-Csv -Path "\iteminfo.txt" –NoTypeInformation 

$users = Get-Content "\iteminfo.txt" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Csv

# Table name
$tabName = "Report"

#Create Table object
$table = New-Object system.Data.DataTable "$tabName"

#Define Columns
$AddCol = {}

$col1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "User Name",([string])
$col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Email Address",([string])
$col3 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Login ID",([string])
$col4 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Creation date",([string])
$col5 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Last logon date",([string])
$col6 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Last password reset",([string])
$col7 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Enabled",([string])
$col8 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Locked",([string])

#Add the Columns
$table.columns.add($col1)
$table.columns.add($col2)
$table.columns.add($col3)
$table.columns.add($col4)
$table.columns.add($col5)
$table.columns.add($col6)
$table.columns.add($col7)
$table.columns.add($col8)

ForEach ($item in $users)
{
        $userdata = (Get-ADUser -identity $item.SamAccountName -properties Name,EmailAddress,SamAccountName,LastLogonDate,whenCreated,passwordlastset,Enabled,lockedout )

        #Create a row
        $row = $table.NewRow()

        #Enter data in the row
        $row."User name" = ($userdata."Name")
        $row."Email Address" = ($userdata.EmailAddress)
        $row."Login ID" = ($userdata.SamAccountName)
        $row."Creation date" = ($userdata."created")
        $row."Last logon date" = ($userdata."LastLogonDate")
        $row."Last password reset" = ($userdata."PasswordLastSet")
        $row."Enabled" = ($userdata."Enabled")
        $row."Locked" = ($userdata."Lockedout")

        #Add the row to the table
        $table.Rows.Add($row)

}
#Communication template
#Creating head style
$Head = @"

<style>
  body {
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 8pt;
    color: #4C607B;
    }
  th, td { 
    border: 1px solid #e57300;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 5px;
    }
  th {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #003366;
    color: #ffffff;
    }
  td {
    color: #000000;
    }
  .even { background-color: #ffffff; }
  .odd { background-color: #bfbfbf; }
</style>

"@

# Creating body
[string]$body = [PSCustomObject]$table | select -Property "User name","Email Address","User ID","Creation date","Last logon date","Last password reset","Enabled","Locked" | sort -Property "User name"  | ConvertTo-HTML -head $head -Body "<font color=`"Red`"><h4> Account(s) Created In The Last 30 Days and Status </h4></font>"
```

**Additional note regarding your script**

Because you are using `Get-ADUser` for each users in the report after import, some of the things such as LastLogonDate / PasswordLastSet won't be the values you exported, but the most actual values from AD.

**A simplified version**

In all cases, you do not have any need for data table and data rows here. 
You can simply use Select to assign custom labels to your data and convert it directly to html from there (Note that I removed the secondary `Get-AdUser` here to use the CSV report data instead but if you wanted to query AD again, you could do it in a similar fashion without datatable / datarow).

```
$users = Get-Content "\iteminfo.txt" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Csv

$Head = @"

<style>
  body {
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 8pt;
    color: #4C607B;
    }
  th, td { 
    border: 1px solid #e57300;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 5px;
    }
  th {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #003366;
    color: #ffffff;
    }
  td {
    color: #000000;
    }
  .even { background-color: #ffffff; }
  .odd { background-color: #bfbfbf; }
</style>

"@


# Creating body
[string]$body = $users | Sort -Property Name |
select @{Name = 'User Name';Expression = {$_.Name}},
@{Name = 'Email Address';Expression = {$_.EmailAddress}},
@{Name = 'Login ID';Expression = {$_.SamAccountName}},
@{Name = 'Creation date"';Expression = {$_.created}},
@{Name = 'Last logon date';Expression = {$_.LastLogonDate}},
@{Name = 'Last password reset';Expression = {$_.PasswordLastSet}},
Enabled,
@{Name = 'Locked';Expression = {$_.Lockedout}} | 
ConvertTo-HTML -head $head -Body "<font color=`"Red`"><h4> Account(s) Created In The Last 30 Days and Status </h4></font>"
```

Comment: Hi Saga, you just saved me a lot of time and frustration. Thanks a lot for the simplifying the code. It worked perfectly. I mean both code, I only update $_.created to $_.whencreated and they worked great. Thanks